# How to pass data cuvidParseVideoData

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, nvidia, rtp

I try to develop streaming program,I have 4k videos that 5 fps and 20 seconds, I encode frames with cuda encoder successfully, i send encoded data over rtp successfully but when i try to decode that data, i got 0 frame from `cuvidParseVideoData`. Should i do something before the `cuvidParseVideoData` for example use ffmpeg demuxer ?

RecvDec.cpp

```
Server* server = new Server(8890 + thread_no);
server->recv_packets();
totBuf* totBuf = server->getTotalBuf();
            if (totBuf->perBuf == nullptr) {
                
                std::cout << prompt << "perBuf null!" << std::endl;
                nVideoBytes = 1;
                continue;
            }

pVideo = new uint8_t[totBuf->totSize];
memcpy(pVideo, totBuf->perBuf->perBuf, totBuf->totSize);
nVideoBytes = totBuf->perBuf->size;
int nFrameReturned = 0;
nFrameReturned = dec.Decode(pVideo, nVideoBytes);
```

NvDecoder.cpp

```
int NvDecoder::Decode(const uint8_t *pData, int nSize, int nFlags, int64_t nTimestamp)
{
    m_nDecodedFrame = 0;
    m_nDecodedFrameReturned = 0;
    CUVIDSOURCEDATAPACKET packet = { 0 };
    packet.payload = pData;
    packet.payload_size = nSize;
    packet.flags = nFlags | CUVID_PKT_TIMESTAMP;
    packet.timestamp = nTimestamp;
    if (!pData || nSize == 0) {
        packet.flags |= CUVID_PKT_ENDOFSTREAM;
    }
    NVDEC_API_CALL(cuvidParseVideoData(m_hParser, &packet));
    m_cuvidStream = 0;

    return m_nDecodedFrame;
}
```

Decode function always returns 0.
If i have to pass my datas from Ffmpeg demuxer, how can i pass type of uint8_t* data to demuxer ?
My data always starts with 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01. This is start frame tag.

Comment: cuvid is not cuda

Comment: it looks to me like this always is returning 0, because you are initializing `m_nDecodedFrame` to 0 at the top, and then returning it having never modified it.